# How to get to know how many words are there in a Sitecore Content Item

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am looking to get to know about how many words and characters are there in a particular Content Item using Sitecore powershell. I know how to do it for a file. for ex:

```
Get-Content C:\testfile.txt | Measure-Object –Line -Word
```

but unable to do it for a content item. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

This would do you count for the `text` field for the home item.

```
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:\content\home"
$measure =  $item["text"] | Measure-Object –Line -Word
echo $measure
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @chris but I am getting an error while executing this script. Refer screen shot **https://prnt.sc/opfgoi**.

Comment: And that is just from running my code? It runs fine for me. Can you post your code of different.

Comment: Yes, that is just by running your code. i have just changed path value in it. rest remains the same.